# show shared image as thumbnail in facebook sharing in Laravel

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to add share button to albums in website created in Laravel. I have used the code for share button that generated using facebook/developer. The albums are not fixed. It is displaying by fetching from database. So I changed code little to change the link of each album automatically as given below.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://mysite/albumphotos/{{$album->name}}"  data-layout="button">
</div>
```

But if I try to share into my facebook account, it is showing some other images in my website. How can I show images in my particular album as thumbnail while sharing??

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @CBroe, first things first:

1. Make sure you have the proper [OG Meta Tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags)
2. Run one of the albums' link in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and check if the crawler is pulling the right info

If the date from step 2 doesn't match what you are looking for, update your OG meta tags and try again.

Comment: I saw OG meta tags. But this meta tags, we can add only in <head>, is it? So this  OG meta tag image will be permanent. But In my album, images will change, depends on database entry. So I need one of the images in album as thumbnail. Is there any another option?

Comment: Well, all you need to do is put that image in the `og:image` meta tag and re-scrape. Did you try that and it didn't work?